# Is this a good deal for a laptop?

Tags: laptop

ok so im trying to purchase a laptop but I dont have that much money on hand. Friend selling me new 15.6 inch laptop with intel core i7-4700mq 2.4ghz processor 8gb ddr3l ram, 1tb 5400 rpm hard drive for $599 oh yeah its a toshiba. THANKS!

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

Comment: Erm, no, we arn't actually evil. This kind of question however is very clearly in the list of sort of questions we close, and purchase recommendation type questions are frowned on. We do have [help] for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that frightens me is the hard drive speed being slightly slower than todays traditional HD's but I think I'm just remembering Desktop HD's speeds. Oh well for $600 you'd be getting a better deal than a MacBook.

Depends on intended use but I say its pretty much good for games of today. Well depends on the graphics but other than that. Green flags a go.

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard to answer without knowing things like its purpose, condition, what you value most in a laptop, your individual use cases for it, etc.  I'm going out on a limb here and guessing you want a laptop to play neopets in art class or something.

An educated guess of the quality and capability based on the parts you listed suggests it's a fine deal, and will last you a few years at least.  The disk might bottleneck you a little bit during startup or launching a program, but lucky you, that's typically the easiest and cheapest piece to upgrade.

Hope that helped some.